# Android Kotlin, Item at specific position of recyclerview changes while scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recyclerview that displays items taken from an api. The items are displayed properly but when scolling, at specific position the item changes when scrolling. When you scroll up one item is shown when you scroll down another item is shown. If you scroll further down in the list another item does the same? What could be the problem?

Here my adapter

```
private lateinit var binding: ItemIssueBinding
private var issueList = mutableListOf<Issue>()
private lateinit var context: Context

inner class MyViewHolder(val binding: ItemIssueBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

fun setIssuesList(list: MutableList<Issue>) {
    issueList = list
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun extendList(list: MutableList<Issue>) {
    issueList.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    binding = ItemIssueBinding.inflate( LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    context = parent.context
    return MyViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return issueList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = issueList[position]

    binding.tvTitle.text = item.title
    binding.tvUsername.text = item.user.login
    loadUserImage(binding.ivUserImage, item.user.avatar_url)

    binding.tvDateCreated.text = "Created at: " + getCreatedClosedDateFormat(item.created_at)

    if (item.closed_at == null) {
        binding.tvDateClosed.text = ""
    } else {
        binding.tvDateClosed.text = "Closed at: " + getCreatedClosedDateFormat(item.closed_at)
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please put the video ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `binding` variable in `RecyclerView` scope, that's why the data is set to the wrong `ViewHolder`'s binding object

Use binding object from your `ViewHolder` instead:

```
holder.binding.tvTitle.text = item.title
holder.binding.tvUsername.text = item.user.login
loadUserImage(holder.binding.ivUserImage, item.user.avatar_url)
```

In `onCreateViewHolder` just simply inflate and pass the binding object to the ViewHolder, don't save the binding object variable like that.